# How to get these files as elegant as possible?

Tags: c#, .net, getfiles

I have some files in the form of:

```
blur.static.shadereffect
blur.dynamic.shadereffect
blur.virtual.shadereffect

soften.static.shadereffect
soften.dynamic.shadereffect
soften.virtual.shadereffect

median.static.shadereffect
median.dynamic.shadereffect
median.virtual.shadereffect

...
```

Right now I am getting the `.static.shadereffect` files and then filtering out the last 2 parts so only the name exists like `"blur", "soften", "median"`, etc.

Some shader effects can have more or less types so I don't want to hard code `.static.shadereffect`.

So in the end the method will return the names of the `.shadereffect` files:

```
{"blur", "soften", "median"}
```

How do I do this most elegantly with as little code as possible? Performance is not important.

EDIT: A small detail. The file names can also have more than 2 dots, so something like "blur.sharpen.dynamic.shadereffect", which shouldn't throw off the results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just use `string.Split` for each filename, and then `Distinct`:

```
    files
    .Select( filename => filename.Split( '.' )[0] )
    .Distinct()
```

Although, I must admit, this may not be the most efficient way. If you have long names with many dots, this will waste some memory and time. A better way would be to explicitly take the portion of the string up to the first dot:

```
    files
    .Select( filename => new string( filename.TakeWhile( c => c != '.' ).ToArray() ) )
    .Distinct()
```

Comment: Thanks I will probably use this but if there were more dots, then this wouldn't give correct results, right? It doesn't have more than 2 dots but I was thinking if it did.

Comment: @Joan Venge: Yes, this will work with any number of dots, including zero. It will give you the first word (i.e. the portion of the string before the first dot), regardless of how many words there is.

Comment: Thanks guys, I see what you mean. I was mainly thinking of getting the full name with all the dots, except xxx.shadereffect for each unique element. But I guess I shouldn't try to make it more generic by having any number of dots for the actual name itself.

Comment: @Joan wanting that is no problem. Your question just didn't specify what you want in the case of more than two dots.

Comment: @Fyodor, out of curiosity Is your second edit for the multiple dot case? Because isn't that also going to take the .xxx.shadereffect part? Also why do you use .ToArray before Distinct?

Comment: @Joan Verge: My second edit does exactly the same thing as the first: returns the first word regardless of the number of dots. The second edit is a bit more efficient, while the original version is a bit more "elegant". I do not use ToArray before Distinct. Please read carefully.

Comment: No I mean in your second code, there is a call to ToArray, that appears before the Distinct call, on line 2. What's that for?

Comment: @Joan: The `String` constructor only accepts an array of `char`, so I have to make an array before calling the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't test it, so there might be some off-by-one bug somewhere. But this should select everything except the last two parts of each string.

```
files
    .Select( s=> 
      {
         int dot1=s.LastIndexOf(".");
         int dot2=s.LastIndexOf(".",dot1-1);
         s.SubString(0,dot2-1);
      }
     )
    .Distinct()
```